# Quotation marks too close with newtxtext

Tags: spacing, kerning

I couldn't find anything regarding my question.
I found that the quotation marks are too close to the text, especially with the newtxtext font I use. It's most visible at the closing quotes after stuff

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{newtxtext}


\begin{document} 
    \textbf{\Huge``Latex document about some stuff''}

    {\Huge``Latex document about some stuff''} 

    \textbf{``Latex document about some stuff''}

    ``Latex document about some stuff''
\end{document}
```

I think it might be a font related issue as I removed all other packages (inluding csquotes and microtype). But it seems the qoutes are also pretty close in the Latex standard fonts.
I left it there in \Huge and bold as I detected it in a title, but as you can see it occurs also in regular size and non-bold. Can I change this with the microtype package and kerning somehow?

Any help would be appreciated, as my thesis is almost done and now it should also "look good".

Comment: Looks like some gnarly font metrics at work.  As an aside, I see that it affects not only the `ff` ligature, but also a plain `f`, as well.

Comment: You can manually fix it with `stuff\/''`, which applies an italic correction.

Comment: Thanks, this fix at least helps in the title, where it is super obvious.

Comment: Note that (unless producing special effects) you should only change font size for an entire paragraph. If you use `\Huge` without ending the paragraph, the line spacing will be completely wrong.

Comment: I recommend amending your code to load `tgtermes` rather than `newtxtext`. This is because the underlying issue seems to be in TeX Gyre Termes and not something introduced by the `newtxtext` package itself.

Comment: I'd report the issue to GUST, I think. It affects the opentype, too.

Comment: The \Huge is part of my title page. And I end the title with \\
Currently I load my fonts like this: \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[scaled=.86]{helvet}
\renewcommand*{\ttdefault}{lmtt}
With tgtermes I get a lot of errors, because of scaling. I have to check this.

And, what is GUST?

Comment: GUST is the Polish TeX user group, some of them have been developing the TeX Gyre fonts: http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre